# Creating new column based on parts of strings in another column in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table, string

I have a column with zoning names (with `"subzones"` like UV036, UMTs2 etc.) and would like to create a new column with the general zone instead (UV instead of UV036, UMT instead of UMTs2... as you see it is not always the same number of letters or the same structure).

I tried to do this in the field calculator:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN "c_zonage_b" LIKE 'UH%%%%' THEN 'UH'
    WHEN "c_zonage_b" LIKE 'UE%%%%' THEN 'UE'
    WHEN "c_zonage_b" LIKE 'N%%%%'  THEN 'N'
    ELSE ''
END
```

(I also specify which column I want this to be in in the field calculator).

`%` are wildcards to take into account any possible subzone (sometimes the subzone includes numbers or letters and their number vary, but it never is more than four hence the `%%%%`).

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: One `%` should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use case if you want to extract text from same column. You can use the following expression in the Field Calculator to extract the capital letters in the new column as follows:

[image]

```
regexp_replace( "Name" ,'([A-Z]+)(.+)','\\1')
```

The output will be like this:

[image]

This expresion `'([A-Z]+)'` captures the capital letters, which is the first part of the string, and `'\\1'` is to select the first group.

This expression `'(.+)'` captures the rest of the string. If you want to populate another column for the second part of the string, then you can use the following expression:

```
regexp_replace( "Name" ,'([A-Z]+)(.+)','\\2')
```

Just replace `\\1` with `\\2` to capture the second group.

[image]

Comment: Nice trip to the unexplored depths of the field calculator expressions. Are those things like `(.+)` listed anywhere? Do they follow a logic described somewhere? Because I really struggle with this sometimes.

Comment: @Erik It is one of the basics of regular expression. `.` matches any single character, the plus sign `+` indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding element, and the `( )` defines a marked subexpression or group. Put them together it becomes select any single character occurred one or more times and put them in a group. Because I defined previously another group with `([A-Z]+)`, I can select the first group with `\\1` and the second group with `\\2`. You can refer to [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: @Erik Also you can test the expression using [regex101](https://regex101.com/), it a great place to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's great! I have encountered a weird issue, I don't know if is related to my file or your expression though:
sometimes your expression worked correctly, for instance NDb became ND, but sometimes it only took the first letter of the string, for instance UZ becomes U. 
Here is the link to the shapefile if you want to have a look:
https://we.tl/t-MpjlJZmLEA

c_zonage_b is the original column and c_zonage_s the simplified one. Thank you!

Comment: @ahmadhanb OK, I found when it happens: when there are no lower case letter after the initial capital letters. In this case UH for instance becomes U, and UVP becomes UV. But I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: And if I do '\\2' I get "H" and "P".

Comment: i think in this case I could also only keep capital letters, it would also work fine. Will see how to do that.

Comment: @PhilippeMorgan It has slightly strange behavior, but try this expression instead `regexp_substr( "c_zonage_b",'([A-Z]+)')`. By the way, `c_zonage_s` has `interger64` field type, you need to choose `string` field type.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much, it really helps!

Comment: @PhilippeMorgan you are welcome. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @ahmadhanb,  nice answer. Can you be so kind and refer me to a sort of tutorial/documentation where I may comprehend the regex?

Comment: @Taras Although QGIS uses different regex system or language, but personally I focused on studying python regex. As introduction, you can refer to [PY4E - Regular Expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovZsvN67Glc). If you want to dig deeper, [Master Python Regular Expression](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Python-Regular-Expressions-F%C3%A9lix-ebook/dp/B00IM5UW3U) is a good source.

Comment: Thank you so much!